# How do travel times of electrons during a double slit experiment behave when looked at from distinct places on detector?

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Let's say we have a standard double-slit experiment setup. We are firing electrons through 2 slits at the screen of the detectors.

Since the detector is flat, from classical mechanics' perspective electrons should arrive earlier in the center part of the detector screen because it is the closest to the electron canon. The further from the middle of the detector screen the longer it takes the electron to travel there (because of a longer path).

Is this rule kept in reality?

If not how would arrival times in relation to position on a flat detector screen behave?

Comment: An interesting question. Found this article in phys. rev https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.77.014102?ft=1 . It seems that the timing has interference patterns so the arrival time is affected.

Comment: Well this should be the answer. /\